# IllegalArgumentException when running app. (Android)

Tags: java, android, exception

When running my project, I get this error.

```
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid resource path: C:\Android\Source Code and Samples\turbo-editor-master\turbo-editor-master\app\src\main\res
```

- Any idea what is causing this?

I am using source code from the Turbo Editor app and have done no changes to the app prior to running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. While looking at the error, follow the path that it is referring to. If there is no path like that, or a file missing, then create it and move the file to that path. Should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try two things:
    - Clean your project. This helps most of the times
    - Go to the directory mentioned in the Exception.             Make sure it actually exists.

Comment: I accidentally submitted an answer :/

Comment: But cleaning has no effect and i do not see the file. Should i create it?

Answer (score 0):

Illegal argument exception is throwed when a function gets wrong (it cannot reasonably deal with it) argument. This can be caused by, for example, missing function that was somewhere overrided. In your case - maybe this is issue with path? I'm not sure but if the path exists you can try changing it so it does not have "spaces" and capital letters. Please dump complete log with error.

Comment: This is from the Gradle Console. Is this what you are looking for? (I just found this also and I did no edits prior to running)http://tny.cz/0ac975f4

Comment: good job, what was the error? Submit it as an answer - maybe someone will encounter similar problem and will be able to deal with it on the spot.